# Animating Widget to a position outside of it's parent (Row/Listview)

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a list of card widgets inside a row or listview. When clicking on of these cards i want to create an effect where the card grows and moves to the middle of the screen, and the rest of the screen appears below a grey overlay.
These example images should help you understand what i'm trying to explain.

Image #1 - List before Clicking in any card

[image]

Image #2 - After clicking a card. The card animates in size and position to the center of the screen. Everything else gets becomes dark. (Ignore bad Photoshop).

[image]

I'm not asking for full code or anything, just want to know if it's possible to move a widget outside it's parent and get some ideas of how to achieve this effect. I know AnimatedContainer can be used on the card to make it grow, the positioning part is what need help with. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `transform:` argument on a `Container()`

**Full Working Example**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Container(
          color: Colors.black87,
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 100),
          child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
                transform: Matrix4.translationValues(0, 50, 0),
                color: Colors.red,
                height: 100,
                width: 100,
              ),
              Container(

                margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
                color: Colors.red,
                height: 100,
                width: 100,
              ),
              Container(

                margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
                color: Colors.red,
                height: 100,
                width: 100,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        )
      )
    );
  }
}
```

The #2 Animation can be accomplished by using a `Hero()` Widget and `Overlay()`. Or you can use a custom `DialogBuilder` just a few Suggestions to get you started.